# Sending Multiple Dictionary Variables as one in Template

Tags: django, django-models

I have a dataset in multiple dictionary variables that I want to pass as Template

```
servera = {'svr': ServerA, 'tc': 10, 'bs': 100, 'bf': 0, 'te': 0, 'per': '0.00'}
serverb = {'svr': ServerB: 'tc': 20, 'bs': 20,  'bf': 0, 'te': 0, 'per': '0.00'}
```

.
..
.
and so on around 14 like this

I want to pass them to template as below

```
def function(request)

#process data using code

return render(request,'output.html'{servera:servera,serverb:serverb,serverc:serverc,.......}
```

While this works, this increases efforts when adding a dictionary variable, need to add it to the return statement.

How can I achieve below

```
somevariable = <all dictionary variabled clubbed>


def function(request)

#process data using code

return render(request,'output.html'{somevariabe:somevariable}
```

and then how will I access that in the Templates

Something like

```
{% for name in somevariable.list.all %}

{% for servername in name.list.all %}

{{ servername.tc }}

{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Any Help will be appreciated

**EDIT :**

Following is what I am trying my Template File

```
{% for k in server_stats.all %}

                <tr>
                    <td><p class="small">{{ forloop.counter  }}</p></td>
                    <td><p class="small">{{ k.svr }}</p></td>
                    <td><p class="small">{{ k.te }}</p></td>
                    <td><p class="small">{{ k.bs    }}</p></td>
                    <td><p class="small">{{ k.bf }}</p></td>
                </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

My Views File Snippet

```
.
.
..
    elif request.method =='POST' and 'weekly_report' in request.POST :
            generate_backup_report("Weekly")
            report_type ="Weekly"
            rc= {'report_type': report_type}
            for m in mserver_list:
                answer = (getbackup_stats(m))
                print(answer)
                server_stats.append(answer)
                print('Getting Stats for ',m)
            print('These are Server Stats',server_stats)
            return render(request,'viewreport.html',{'mserver_list':mserver_list,'server_stats':server_stats,'tstats':tstats})
```

The Debug Toolbaar shows that the Variable has transferred successfully to the Template, but cant take values out of it.

```
'server_stats': [{'bf': 0,
                   'bs': 0,
                   'per': '0.00',
                   'svr': <masterserver: ServerA>,
                   'tc': 0,
                   'te': 0},
                  {'bf': 1,
                   'bs': 4,
                   'per': '-100.00',
                   'svr': <masterserver: Challenger>,
                   'tc': 5,
                   'te': 5},
                  {'bf': 1,
                   'bs': 18,
                   'per': '-100.00',
                   'svr': <masterserver: Serverb>,
                   'tc': 21,
                   'te': 19},
                  {'bf': 0,
                   'bs': 0,
                   'per': '0.00',
                   'svr': <masterserver: ServerC>,
                   'tc': 0,
                   'te': 0},
                  {'bf': 12,
                   'bs': 0,
                   'per': '-1200.00',
                   'svr': <masterserver: ServerD>,
                   'tc': 21,
                   'te': 12},
                  {'bf': 1,
                   'bs': 29,
                   'per': '-100.00',
                   'svr': <masterserver: ServerE>,
                   'tc': 31,
                   'te': 30},
                  {'bf': 30,
                   'bs': 0,
                   'per': '-3000.00',
                   'svr': <masterserver: ServerF>,
                   'tc': 32,
                   'te': 30},
                  {'bf': 0,
                   'bs': 0,
                   'per': '0.00',
                   'svr': <masterserver: ServerG>,
                   'tc': 0,
                   'te': 0},
                  {'bf': 1,
                   'bs': 27,
                   'per': '-100.00',
],
```

Comment: why not make a list of  server dictionaries and send them to the template and iterate over them in template?Like `server_lsit = [servera, serverb, .....]` in context send them as ` ''outpt.html, {'servers': server_list}`

Comment: Hi Sammy,  I tried that , but unlike Dictionary, I am not able to understand how to fetch data out of it from template. I am using similar Template code to extract it , but unsuccessful.  Can you help with how will I get data out of server_list variable in the Template.

Comment: I have written an answer, just see if that works

Comment: Can you remove .all from the for loop in template and try

Comment: Damm !!!! That worked... It took a lot of time and the 'all' was holding it all the time... Thanks Sammy !!!!!

Before we close this, Can you tell me whats with 'all'. I have been using it all along and it did not cause any issues. what does presence of all and absence of it changes ?

Comment: Ya that's how i had written in the answer too.You must use .all only when you are referencing many to many fields of the current object, suppose inside the loop let's say svr is many to many object, then you must use svr.all and iterate over it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a list of server dictionaries and send them to the template and iterate over them in template.Like `server_lsit = [servera, serverb, .....]` in context send them as `''outpt.html, {'servers': server_list}`

In your html template you can iterate like,
`{% for serv in servers %} {{ serv.svr }}{{ serv.tc }} ... {% endfor %}`

Every time the loop runs it is on each server and you can access the data there.This is just one way to do it maybe there is a better way too.

Comment: This does not work  . The Output is blank. Theoretically, I also think it should work .

Comment: Hi @iVaibhav can you update the question with what you have tried?